# Postgres: Order by string column with known values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have an `events` table with a `state` column. If everything goes according to plan, the states can only be one of:

- `scheduled`
- `invited`
- `notified`
- `started`
- `ended`

Is it possible to order by `state` and specify which value comes first, second, third, etc...?

**Bonus Points:** Is there a way to do this easily in Rails 3?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

1.If you just need a sql in postgres, here it is :

```
select * from events
order by (case state 
          when 'scheduled' then 1
          when 'notified' then 2
          when 'invited' then 3
          when 'started' then 4
          when 'ended' then 5 
          end)
```

you can change the order of states in sql, no need to change the ruby code, play the sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/976e9/3.

2.In mu's suggestion, you can use a enum type, it's more efficient, if you need to change the order, you can recreate the enum. see this sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/f6f3d/2

```
CREATE TYPE states AS ENUM ('invited', 'scheduled', 'notified', 'started', 'ended');
create table events(
  name varchar(100),
  state states
);

select * from events order by state;
```

3.In pure ruby way, you can define a hash:

```
test_hash = {'scheduled'=>1, 'notified'=>2, 'invited'=>3, 'started'=>4, 'ended'=>5}
Events.all.sort! {|x, y| test_hash[x.state] <=> test_hash[y.state]}
```

4.But in my opinion, you should add a table named "states", with columns "name" and "sequence", and specify the order in "sequence". Join the "events" and "states" then. When you change the order, you don't need to change the code.

Comment: You could also use an `enum` type in PostgreSQL, they sort sensibly. OTOH, trying to get AR to play nice with an `enum` could be more work than it is worth.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I know little about `enum`, I tried it and added your suggestion to the answer, do I understand correctly? If there are something wrong. please point it, thank you:)

Comment: ["The ordering of the values in an enum type is the order in which the values were listed when the type was created."](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-enum.html#AEN6387) So, yeah, what you have is another option. But I'm not sure how well ActiveRecord will play with that.