# Rails order by string column value through joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a `LibraryEntry` model with a string column `status` which belongs to a `User` model.

I want to find all `LibraryEntry` models that belong to a `User` where I can set a priority for the value of the string column `status` to sort the model.

For example to sort the model in this order by the string column `status`: `[watch,complete,drop,backlog,wishlist]`

I have checked this thread [Postgres: Order by string column with known values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649047/postgres-order-by-string-column-with-known-values) and have tried to write my own SQL statement but it didn't work, getting the error `PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "status" is ambiguous`

```
#This is under the model LibraryEntry`
 def self.priority_order
    order("CASE
      WHEN status = 'watch' THEN '1'
      WHEN status = 'complete' THEN '2'
      WHEN status = 'wishlist' THEN '3'
      WHEN status = 'drop' THEN '4'
      WHEN status = 'backlog' THEN '5'
    END")
  end
 #The query to sort the model in the controller
 @lib = @user.library_entries.priority_order.joins(:vn).order('vns.name')
```

`status` can be either

- `watch`
- `complete`
- `drop`
- `backlog`
- `wishlist`

Comment: "... but it didn't work" -- more details please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're joining to another table (user) which also has a column named status.

In your order, prefix status with the name of the LibraryEntry table.

Presumably:

```
def self.priority_order
  order("CASE
    WHEN library_entries.status = 'watch' THEN '1'
    WHEN library_entries.status = 'complete' THEN '2'
    WHEN library_entries.status = 'wishlist' THEN '3'
    WHEN library_entries.status = 'drop' THEN '4'
    WHEN library_entries.status = 'backlog' THEN '5'
  END")
end
```

... or ...

```
def self.priority_order
  order("CASE library_entries.status
    WHEN 'watch'    THEN '1'
    WHEN 'complete' THEN '2'
    WHEN 'wishlist' THEN '3'
    WHEN 'drop'     THEN '4'
    WHEN 'backlog'  THEN '5'
  END")
end
```

This is always a good practice when including SQL fragments in your Rails code.